# why can't the logarithmic base/parameter be negative?

Tags: logarithms

I read the domain of a logarithmic function can not be negative, but why?

I mean, a logarithmic function with base $-2$ and parameter $-1/8$ should result in the exponent $-3$ shouldn't it?

Comment: If you're prepared for complex results, then I don't see why you can't have a negative base. I presume you know the base change formula?

Comment: Do you define logarithm as inverse of exponential functions?

Comment: @velutluna first line of wikipedia: "In mathematics, the logarithm is the inverse operation to exponentiation.", so kinda.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician so you may actually do it?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359855/why-arent-logarithms-defined-for-negative-x)

Comment: Well, you need to answer my question first: do you know the base change formula for logarithms?

Comment: $y= log_a(x)$ is equivalent to $x= a^y$.  If you allow a to be negative you may run into problems with fractional powers such as $(-2)^{1/2}$.  There may not be a problem with specific values such as the ones you give but we need the logarithm to be a **function** that applies to all positive numbers.

Comment: Then it depends on whether you can define $a^x$ when $a<0$.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician yes, I do, and I see what goes wrong there, but it shouldn't take away the idea behind the function, because the example i gave should work out.

Comment: "I see what goes wrong there" - then you know that it's possible to choose a branch of the complex logarithm apart from the principal branch, no?

Comment: if you mean logical thinking, yes

Answer (score 0):

Well.. logarithms are functions, functions with some properties. The basic rule of defining a function is that it should be useful.

You may argue with your examples like $(-2)^3=-8$ but I can counter with things like $(-2)^n=4$.  You surely don't want to make changes in a function which only apply for odd powers of base.

Furthermore, when you make changes and start dealing with things like log$_{a} x$ when x is negative then you get multiple results, or your logarithmic function becomes multi valued. For instance $(-2)^3=-8$ but $(-2)^{1.09284065−0.420787248i}=-8$ too. Remember that multi valued function thing?
I hope its enough.