# $\log$ to the base $-2$ of $-8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Can I say that the answer is $3$?

When I exponentiated both sides I got:

$$ (-2)^3 = -8$$

But I am being told that negative logarithms cannot occur. Why is this?

Comment: The base of logarithm must always be strictly positive and different from 1. Otherwise you can calculate ""logarithm"" only in some very specifical cases like the one you posted. If I asked you the ""logarithm"" in base -2 of -3 ?(if we stay in real numbers)

Comment: Look in your book for the "definition" of logarithm.  Maybe $(-2)^3$ makes sense, but $(-2)^{3.1}$ doesn't (in the real numbers).  For most $y$ there is no (real) solution $x$ to the equation $(-2)^x = y$.  So the convention is that $\log_a$ is defined only for $a>1$.  Maybe (in strange circumstances) also for $0 < a < 1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't logarithms defined for negative $x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359855/why-arent-logarithms-defined-for-negative-x)